# Steam not opening. Missing lib something file

Tags: steam

So i had to reinstall ubuntu because nothing was opening, and on that Ubuntu steam was working perfectly  (one problem though, i can't remember if i used the .deb or the cmd line). So i reinstalled steam, and I'm using the same version of Linux, i am missing many lib files. But i used the .deb file, so is it just the .deb file or is it just my computer?

So when i downloaded steam with the deb file, it launched with the package installer but when it downloaded, i got the problem that the lib files where not downloaded. It happened before, on MX Linux, and i couldn't fix it. So is it going to be one of those things?

Comment: Steam is in the repositories, so if you run `sudo apt install steam` it should install all needed libraries as well. No need to download a .deb file.

Comment: @Terrance Ok, thank you. I will do that. Thanks for your help